# Is there a way to stop calling SheetBeforeDoubleClick method in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two addings and in both the addins I have `SheetBeforeDoubleClick` method. Whenever I user is double clicking on cell, both the addin methods are getting called. I tried using flag and i am able to manage it with the flag check. But is there any other standard way to identified the active ribbon/addin and perform the double click?

```
Private Sub myAppEvents_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean){
    MsgBox("Double Clicked...")
}
```

Update:

After all my research, we can't avoid `SheetBeforeDoubleClick` method getting called but we need to handle this case by validating the activeAddin or sheet details.

Comment: ASre both addins written by you?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem. As `MyAppEvents_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` is a event method, It will get called everywhere its being used. Hence I have added additional check inside the method to check active add-in. This solved my problem.